# Mis-indexed char[] arrays in Visual Studio 2005

Tags: arrays, visual-c++, visual-studio-2005, pointers

I'm at a loss to explain what seems to be mis-addressing within the `char[]` arrays of a C++ class I've inherited.  I'm using Visual Studio 2005 and have narrowed the problem down to this:

**MyClass.h:**

```
class MyClass {
public:
  MyClass();
  virtual ~MyClass();
  void Reset();
  // More member functions. . .

  char m_szString[128];
  // More member variables. . .
}
```

**MyClass.cpp:**

```
MyClass::MyClass() { Reset(); }
MyClass::Reset()   { m_szString[0] = 'X'; }
// . . .
```

As I single-step through the program, I find that the `Reset()` function actually sets `m_szString[`**`4`**`]` to `'X'` — not `m_szString[`**`0`**`]` as I expected. According to the watch window, the only element in the class before `m_szString[]` is a pointer to the vftable, `__vfptr`, which happens to be 4 bytes.

If I add more member variables to `MyClass`, subsequent strings are mis-addressed by various, always-increasing multiples of 4 bytes.  Not simply *aligned* to 4-byte boundaries, but actually *offset* by multiples of 4.  It's as if the compiler is skipping twice the necessary space for each vftable ... but that's purely a guess.

Somewhat similar problems have been reported (Google, MSDN), but I haven't found any answers.

---

**Additional Information / Partial Solution:**  The class is the only member variable of a wrapper class that becomes a DLL.  The parent was originally declared as

```
class ATL_NO_VTABLE CWrapperClass
```

Removing `ATL_NO_VTABLE` fixed the alignment problem.

I'm still seeing buffer overflows, but those should be fairly easy to track down.

Can you explain `ATL_NO_VTABLE` in terms understandable to an embedded C developer who's had very limited experience with COM beyond BSTRs, or better yet, provide a pointer (sorry) to a good reference?

---

*Still More:*  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7525/) provides some helpful debugging information.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you use print statements and try this in release mode?

Comment: Can you give a *complete* working example demonstrating the problem?

Comment: There has to be more than you're mentioning here - the comment about "adjustor thunks" makes me suspicious for example.

Comment: @Andrew: And so there is, as I'm now aware.  I'm still spelunking in the code, ever more confused by COM.  Thanks for the incentive to keep digging!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The Answer

The compiler was, in fact, calculating an incorrect address for some of the class members.  The culprit turned out to be a **`#pragma pack 1`** directive hidden in an obscure header file that was `#included` in some of the source files.

### How I found it

50% persistence, 50% luck, and 10% math skills.  :-)

I came across a very simple class with few methods and members, most of which were defined in the header file, including:

```
typedef int BOOL;  // Legacy, makes my skin crawl; don't ask.
BOOL isConnected() { return m_bConnected; };
BOOL m_bConnected;
```

...and the function returned `false` when I *knew*  `m_bConnected` was `true`:

- The watch window showed the correct value.  Programmatic changes to `m_bConnected` were reflected in the window.
- A watch on `&m_bConnected` showed that it began 8 bytes into the class.
- The raw memory window showed the correct value.  Programmatic changes to `m_bConnected` were reflected there as well.
- The 4 bytes before `m_bConnected` were all `0`, which I interpreted to be padding.
- Stepping the debugger through the code clearly showed a return value of `false`!

So I checked the disassembly window and found this (comments are mine):

```
mov    eax,dword ptr [this]        ; address of the class instance
mov    eax,dword ptr [eax+4]       ; offset to m_bConnected
```

In other words, the compiler calculated the offset as 4, when it should have been 8.

### Aha!

Interestingly, when I removed the definition of `isConnected()` from the header and placed it into my source file, *the address was calculated correctly*!  That convinced me that it was, indeed, a packing problem, and a search of the code base for `#pragma pack` quickly identified the culprit, an ancient header file that (legitimately) required alignment on 1-byte boundaries but never reset the packing to the default.

### The Fix

The solution was as easy as enclosing the offending header like this:

```
#pragma pack(push)
// original code here
#pragma pack(pop)
```

Thanks for your interest.  And Sara, if you're reading, I'm about to [dance on my desk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183469/how-do-you-reward-yourself-when-youve-overcome-a-monster-task)!

Answer (score 1):

Two questions here:

- What's the problem? I don't mean what seems fishy in the debugger, but what actually goes wrong at the top level? What you're seeing in the debugger could be the result of optimizations, rather than being an actual error.
- Do you have some minimal code that reproduces the error? The above doesn't really tell me much. If I'd run into *exactly* the same problem previously, it might be useful, but I haven't. So if I wanted to reproduce the problem, what should I do?

Comment: Thanks for your reply!  1st symptom was the debugger reporting a buffer overrun as it returned from a function that uses this class.  Further inspection showed the char[] arrays weren't being set as expected, which ultimately led to the 'off by 4' observation.  All optimizations are disabled.

Answer (score 1):

My first guess would be compiling with unintended optimizations turned on.

My second guess would be that something strange is going on with unicode support (e.g. char vs wchar_t).

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts.  The problem was definitely ATL_NO_VTABLE, probably related to COM.  Writing a string of chars to the array does in fact write the correct chars to consecutive elements; it's only the offset that was wrong.  I've quadruple-checked all optimizations -- they're off.

Answer (score -2):

Its always better to null terminate the string before you start using . By doing so even while debugging you will have a cleaner view of the array.
More ever you have declared m_szString in  public . Its better you declare the array in the private area and return it using a member function

Comment: True, but all irrelevant with respect to the question. Regardless of how any of the elements is declared or initialized, the indexing should always be correct.  This is not a question about best practices; it's a question about the way the compiler computes addresses.