# Are there a free Heap corruption detection tools for windows?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, heap-corruption

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a good Valgrind substitute for Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413477/is-there-a-good-valgrind-substitute-for-windows)

I need to debug and fix my heap corruption error. THere is one for linux  -  valgrind, but are there analogue for windows? I do not search for memory leaks. Memory corruption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. Check out [this list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_program_analysis#Examples_of_Tools), and [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069/heap-corruption-under-win32-how-to-locate).